# maximize the sum of values of array mapped by another array

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-programming, maximize

Lets say I have sheets,

```
Sq.inch 1   2   3   4   5   6
Prices  1   4   5   13  8   12
```

lets say i have 6 sq inch sheet and I want to sell it for maximum profit.

> If I sell whole sheet I can earn 11
>
> If I sell 4 sq inch sheet and 2 sq inch sheet I can earn 13 + 4 = 17

that way I want to write a algorithm to find maximum profit when I have about 10000 Sq inch sheet. That means I have price if each sq inch sheet.

It would better If someone can tell at least what approach I should go to solve this problem.

I can think on two ways to approach this as I don't know can do or not,
1. using linear programming.
2. using Dynamic programming.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: It's a classic [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: From your question it seems Rod Cutting suits your problem statement better. Try this link -> http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/